# Set value to primitive type fields

Tags: java, reflection

This is the first time that I'm working with reflection and I have the following trouble.

I have this class

```
public class MyObject {

    private String description;

    private int number;

    private double value;


    //Constructor getter and setter
}
```

Now I'm trying to set the values of the MyObject's fields.

```
    Class c = Class.forName("myPackage.MyObject");
    Field [] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();


    for(Field field: fields){

         if(f.getType().equals(Double.class)){
        //Do somethings
        }
        else if(f.getType().equals(Integer.class)){
        //Do somethings
        }
        else{
        //Do somethings
        }


    }
}
```

but I'm never able to filter int and double type.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `Double` is not `double`.  Try this instead

```
 if(f.getType() == double.class){
    //Do somethings

 } else if(f.getType() == int.class){
    //Do somethings

 } else {
    //Do somethings
 }
```

A simple way to prove this to yourself is

```
 System.out.println(f.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

`Double.class` refers to the wrapper class, `java.lang.Double`. The primitive `double` is referenced by `Double.TYPE`.

Similarly, you also have `Integer.TYPE`, `Long.TYPE`, etc.

Comment: I prefer `double.class`